# Could the US Federal Government open abortion clinics inside Federal buildings in states where abortion is illegal?

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government, abortion

As an example, [USCIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Citizenship_and_Immigration_Services) has dozens of offices around the US, including many states where abortion is expected to be banned soon. Could the US Federal Government dedicate a part of every USCIS building to an abortion clinic, thus denying the states the opportunity to ban abortion? Or would they still have to comply with state law?

I'm asking about the extent to which the Federal government could change things without amending the Constitution or packing the courts to get a favorable re-assessment of prior case law.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137664/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-could-the-us-federal-government-open-abor).

Comment: Or post offices

Answer (score 13):

The [Hyde Ammendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyde_Amendment) prevents any federal funds from being used to pay for abortions. You can be certain that providing clinic space to provide abortions would be quickly challenged in court as a violation of the Hyde Ammendment.

Comment: Looks like such a clinic won't be challengeable if it only conducted abortions "to save the life of the woman, or if the pregnancy arises from incest or rape".

Comment: What if the government rented the space to the abortion clinic? The government wouldn't be spending funds, it would be coming from the tenant. Isn't this the idea behind Warren's recommendation to use national parks?

Comment: @Barmar: I don't think that would work because the tenant couldn't lawfully exist at all.

Comment: @Greendrake Don't all states have an exception for saving the life of the mother? Some states have an explicit exception for the result of rape or incest too.

Comment: @AndrewLeach States' laws are irrelevant here as we're talking about the Hyde Ammendment which is federal.

Comment: Any law enacting such a provision would override the Hyde Amendment expressly as to that expenditure.

Answer (score 7):

A substantial impediment to this plan is that the Hyde Amendment forbids using federal funds to pay for an abortion. Let us set aside the funding question in favor of the jurisdiction question.

There is such a thing as the ["special maritime and territorial jurisdiction](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/7) of the US, where the federal government claims jurisdiction which therefore supersedes state jurisdiction, but this refers to the high seas, vessels, rocks with guano... It does also include

> (3) Any lands reserved or acquired for the use of the United States,
> and under the exclusive or concurrent jurisdiction thereof, or any
> place purchased or otherwise acquired by the United States by consent
> of the legislature of the State in which the same shall be, for the
> erection of a fort, magazine, arsenal, dockyard, or other needful
> building

USCIS buildings are unlikely to qualify, but there could be some such locations – it would have to be exclusive federal jurisdiction, to preclude application of state law (also known as a federal enclave). A military fort is a likely candidate location.

But [18 USC 13](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/13) says that an act that is not a federal crime but which

> would be punishable if committed or omitted within the jurisdiction of
> the State, Territory, Possession, or District in which such place is
> situated, by the laws thereof in force at the time of such act or
> omission, shall be guilty of a like offense and subject to a like
> punishment.

But this cannot be used to override valid administrative orders, or when there *is* a relevant federal law.

Comment: Do federal office buildings not fall under "other needful building"?  The USCIS offices I know about are in federal office buildings.

Comment: Elizabeth Warren has suggested national parks.

Comment: That does seem most robust, because that is land actually owned by the federal government, ceded to or kept by the states, and is not leased.